# Angular js : manipulate value of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, object

I have dates as date objects.

When i do this

```
$scope.test = new Date([2017,2,15]);

<pre>{{test}}</pre>
<pre>{{test.getDate()}}</pre>
```

I get

"2017-02-14T23:00:00.000Z" and 15

So up to here, we are good.

But in my case, when I try to do the same with a date whitch is in another object like in this schema :

```
 var tachesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    start: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
    end: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
    comment : String,
    state : Boolean,
    projet : { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Projets' }
});
```

I get nothing :(

This code :

```
{{tache.start}}
```

displays the date like this "2017-02-20T23:00:00.000Z"

but

```
<pre>{{tache.start.getDate()}}</pre>
```

displays nothing.

What I missed ?

## EDIT

I've omitted to precise that I want to do this in a ng-repeat

The code below give me dates like "2017-02-20T23:00:00.000Z"

```
<pre ng-repeat="tache in taches">
    {{tache.start}}
</pre>
```

The code below give me nothing

```
<pre ng-repeat="tache in taches">
    {{tache.start.getDay()}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
   {{tachesSchema.start.getDate()}}

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried, but it didn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

You can define a default with a function:

```
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

See docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried, but it didn't change anithing :(

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "String" value when you try {{tache.start}}. You should convert it to Date object (new Date("2017-02-20T23:00:00.000Z")) and try getDate() method.

OR try below:

```
new Schema({
    date: { type: Date, default: '15/02/2017' }
});'
```

Comment: When i do this  $scope.test = new Date([2017,2,15]);

<pre>{{test}}</pre>
<pre>{{test.getDate()}}</pre>

I get

"2017-02-14T23:00:00.000Z" and 15

So I believe that "2017-02-14T23:00:00.000Z" can be manipulated as object. Am I wrong ? 

When i triy the same thing on my real object "tache" in a ng-repeat I get nothing. This is confusing :(

Comment: Please can you share your sample code via jsfiddle / codepen / jsbin?